# How to arrange SQL printed queries in a grid

Tags: php, html, sql, grid, html-table

I have a People table in SQL and I am printing its columns on my website (each column is the name of a person).

I would like these names to arrange in a grid, like a table, but with unlimited vertical height (which will depend on how many names there are in the table), but limited horizontal width, something like 4 names maximum. With the code below everything gets printed in a simple table with 1 column and multiple rows.

How could I do this? Thanks.

```
 <?php
      $new = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM People");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)){           

             print( "  <tr> <td height='40px'><p class='scrollviewed'>   <b>  "  . $row['Field'] . "</b></p></td></tr>");
     }
```

Comment: @SamSegers Yep, the questions is a bit different (column names) but the solution is same.

Comment: mmm, I see. If it's allowed that the number of columns vary in each row, and don't have headers. You can use css float: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but the idea should be sound. basically you want to have a new `TR` every 4 items, indefinitely...

Try something similar to the following:

```
  $cnt = 0;
  $cols = 4;
  $output = "<table><tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)){           
         $output .= "<td height='40px'>{$row['Field']}</td>";
         $cnt++;
         if($cnt % $cols == 0)
         { $output .= "</tr><tr>"; }
  }
  $output .= "</tr></table>";
  echo $output;
```

Comment: That works brilliantly @gmiley, thank you! 
I'm having another problem with the code, it only shows external border and not internal of each cell of the table. How come? I've worked with table before, but I've always seen inside border

Comment: Your best bet is to look into CSS and assigning styles to your tables. Google: `css table style borders` should probably do the trick.

Comment: cheers, merry Christmas!

Comment: Sure, not a problem. If this answers everything please accept it as the answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

First off, start using PDO. It's much better and mysql is deprecated.

You can make your query like this:

```
$new = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM People");
```

Create your table heads. Then you can use something like this:

```
<?php
    while($row = $new->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td height='40px'><p class='scrollviewed'><?= $row['FIELD'] ?></p></td>
```

After you have ALL the td's placed, end it with

```
<?php } ?>
</tr>
```

And so on and on...

Answer (score 0):

//maybe you can use 'col-md-3' from bootstrap

```
echo '<div class="row">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)){           
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">'. $row['name'] .'</div>';     
}

echo '</div>';
```